# Error getting the required output in SendKeys using arrays..

Tags: arrays, vbscript, autoit

I am new to VBScript and AutoIt. I have been trying to make changes to a VBScript (text file) using an AutoIt script by taking input from the user in form of comma-seperated commands and then writing it to a `.vbs` file. I tried to do this by storing the strings in array and then writing it using a `While` loop.

**Example:**

For an input of: `ALPHA,BETA,GAMMA` I am **expecting** an output as follows starting from line *"140"* in the text file

```
WshShell.appactivate "telnet 10.250.124.85"
WScript.Sleep 1999
WshShell.SendKeys"ALPHA"
WshShell.appactivate "telnet 10.250.124.85"
WScript.Sleep 1999
WshShell.SendKeys"BETA"
WshShell.appactivate "telnet 10.250.124.85"
WScript.Sleep 1999
WshShell.SendKeys"GAMMA"
```

Instead, i am **getting** such output:

```
WshShell.appactivate "telnet 10.250.124.85"
WScript.Sleep 1999
WshShell.SendKeys""
WshShell.appactivate "telnet 10.250.124.85"
WScript.Sleep 1999
WshShell.SendKeys""
WshShell.appactivate "telnet 10.250.124.85"
WScript.Sleep 1999
WshShell.SendKeys""
```

I.e. the SendKeys quotes are empty due to some mistake. The code I have used is as follows:

```
$fileadd="C:\Users\rmehta\Downloads\zyxw\Memorycheck.vbs"

$commandnewstring= InputBox("Command Settings","Please enter the commands seperated by commas","")
If @error=0 Then

    Global $count,$usestring,$output
    $usestring=$commandnewstring
    $count= UBound(StringSplit($commandnewstring, ",",""))-1


    Global $a[$count],$line
    $line=140
    $count= $count-1
    $output= StringSplit($usestring,",","")

    While $count >= 0
        $a[$count]= $output
        _FileWriteToLine($fileadd,$line,"WshShell.appactivate" & Chr( 34 ) & "telnet 10.250.124.85" & Chr( 34 ),1)
        _FileWriteToLine($fileadd,$line+1,"WScript.Sleep" & " 1999",1)
        _FileWriteToLine($fileadd,$line+2,"WshShell.SendKeys" & Chr( 34 ) & $a[$count] & Chr( 34 ),1)
        $count=$count-1
        $line=$line+3
    WEnd

Else
    MsgBox(0,"You clicked on Cancel",2)
EndIf
```

I have put in a lot of thought but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: The first line in your while-statement is wrong... The output of StringSplit is an Array. So you'd probably want to use `$a = $output[$count]` instead and later only refer to `$a`. Oh and the third parameter of StringSplit should be a `2`, so you don't have to substract 1 from the UBound, or be left out...

Comment: Thanks @JohannesThomasMeyer , i will try out the changes and let you know :)

Comment: @Johannes, Just some minor changes in the limits of while loop and yeah i am done.Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @JohannesThomasMeyer, That should have been an answer rather than a comment: you are missing out on some rep here :)

Comment: Ok, I'll answer as well...

Comment: I just thought, it would be not worthy a full answer to just give these hints... so I took the time right now to post a complete solution right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a working solution:

```
#include <File.au3>

$fileadd = "C:\Users\rmehta\Downloads\zyxw\Memorycheck.vbs"

$commands = InputBox("Command Settings", "Please enter the commands seperated by commas","")
If @error == 0 Then
    Global $count
    $commands = StringSplit($commands, ",", 2)
    $count = UBound($commands)

    Global $a[$count], $line
    $line = 140

    $index = 0
    While $index < $count
       $command = $commands[$index]
       _FileWriteToLine($fileadd, $line, "WshShell.appactivate" & Chr(34) & "telnet 10.250.124.85" & Chr(34), 1)
       _FileWriteToLine($fileadd, $line + 1, "WScript.Sleep 1999", 1)
       _FileWriteToLine($fileadd, $line + 2, "WshShell.SendKeys" & Chr(34) & $command & Chr(34), 1)
       $line += 3
       $index += 1
    WEnd
Else
    MsgBox(0, "You clicked on Cancel", 2)
EndIf
```

I encourage you to study the differences between your first try and this solution. Learn from the formatting and the usage of spacing as well as from the comparison with `==`, not with `=`. Or the usage of the `+=` operator...

Comment: **==** is used for case-sensitive string comparison, but not for integer comparison. If you use **==** then both values are converted into strings if they are not strings. See http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_operators.htm

Comment: Oh, thank you... I didn't recognise that the `=` operator is overloaded.